# create a query that will display employee name and department number

Tags: sql

hey guys im kinda stuck on this question

create a query that will display employee name, dept nmber and all the employees that work in the same department as a given employee

i was thinking this would be the answer:

```
Select ename,deptno
from emp, dept
```

but thats not the right answer

Comment: Please add a little more details, for example how your table looks like and what you have tried so far to get there.

Comment: I'm sure this will be all covered in your course material. You should read it.

Comment: uhh my lecturer is useless FML @ Martin Smith

Answer (score 3):

```
select name, dept_number from employees 
where dept_num  in 
            (select dept_num from employees where emp_num = given_emp_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee_name,department,department_id,hire_date
from employees
where department ALL(
    select department_id
    from employees
    where department_id=bruce.exclude.bruce
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
  e.last_name "EMP_NAME", d.deptno "DEPT" 
from 
  employees e, 
  dept d
where 
  d.deptno=e.department_id;
```